# WPF ItemsControl content cropping rather than scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a .NET 4.0 WPF application using the MVVM pattern and I've been unable to achieve the desired outcome on one of the screens (UserControl as View).  I have stripped down most of the page to show the core of the problem. The page consists of a grid with three rows and one column. The first row contains header text and the last row contains a Save button. The middle row contains a grid with one row and column and displays an ObservableCollection in an ItemsControl with a data template of a custom user control. There are ten items in the collection and I want them to display in two columns and five rows so I have a WrapPanel as an ItemsPanelTemplate.

I want the ItemsControl to scroll within the available space but it is expanding to the size of content and most of it is being cropped off the bottom of the page.

I am listing the XAML for user control the ObservableCollection uses as a data template and the XAML for the main page below that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<UserControl x:Class="OIL.UserControls.ShopNotes.ShopNoteComponent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="120" d:DesignWidth="150">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="140" Margin="5,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
        <StackPanel Width="120" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Height="25" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="/OIL;component/Images/BlueCam.png">
                <Image.ToolTip>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ToolTipImagePath}" />
                </Image.ToolTip>
            </Image>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource LargeText}" Content="{Binding Path=ComponentTitle}" />
            <CheckBox Width="80" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource NormalText}" Content=" Mandatory?" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=ComponentMandatory, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ComponentSelected}" />
            <CheckBox Width="15" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=ComponentSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And here is the main XAML page:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OIL.View.ConfiguratorViews.Configurator_ShopNotes_Tab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:igWPF="http://infragistics.com/Editors" 
         xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:OIL.UserControls.ShopNotes" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="570" d:DesignWidth="866">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ShopNotesComponentsTemplate">
        <uc:ShopNoteComponent />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border Margin="10" CornerRadius="13" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FF666666">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Height="30" Width="75" Margin="10,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" 
                    Command="{Binding Path=AddNewTemplateCommand}" 
                    Content="Add" />
            <Button Height="30" Width="75" Margin="10,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" 
                    Command="{Binding Path=EditTemplateCommand}" 
                    Content="Edit" />
            <Grid Margin="10,5,0,5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsNewTemplate, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBox Height="30" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource NormalText}" Text="{Binding Path=TemplateDescription}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEditedTemplate, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <igWPF:XamComboEditor Name="cmbShopNotesTemplate" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ShopNoteTemplates, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                          DisplayMemberPath="CONFIGURATION_DESC" 
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedShopNoteTemplate, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                          Value="Select Shop Notes Template" 
                                          NullText="Select Shop Notes Template" 
                                          IsEditable="True">
                    </igWPF:XamComboEditor>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="30" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource NormalText}" Content="* Hover over camera icon to view Shop Note component" />
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ShopNoteComponents, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShopNotesComponentsTemplate}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Width="300" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="30" Width="150" Margin="10,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Background="{x:Null}" 
            Command="{Binding Path=SaveTemplateCommand}" 
            Content="Save" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

EDIT: Changed question title as I have removed the ScrollViewer between starting the question and actually posting it.  Also, noticed the Save button was in the inner grid rather than outer grid so I have corrected that (no change in rendering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ItemsControl` does *not* have its own `ScrollViewer` like a `ListBox`. You can either replace you `ItemsControl` with a `ListBox`, or simply wrap it in a `ScrollViwer`, being careful to move the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` settings like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShopNotesComponentsTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="300" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thank you, Sheridan. That answers my question, at least in the scope of what I have posted here, and I will mark it as the answer. However, my issue was a little broader and more had to be done to implement the solution. I will be adding an additional answer that might help others with similar issues.

Comment: @BrianHancock, while it is admirable that you want to return to provide a complete solution, please do *not* post a solution that contains details that are *not* in this question, as that could confuse users.

Comment: I understand. I have deleted my answer post.